# Create table with foreign key in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
I am using sqlite tool of Mozilla Firefox to manage my database and i have to create a table in which i have to use foreign key . How to do that?
These are my tables,

Table Name:QuestionWithAnswer

Column_Name=Format:
Date=DATETIME(Primary Key),
Question=Text,
Answer=Text,
UserAnswer=Text,
isCorrext=Text.

Table Name:Question
Column_Name=Format:
Question_ID=Integer(Primary Key)
Question=Text


Table Name:Record
Column_Name=Format:
id=integer(Primary Key)
DatewithTime=DATETIME(foreign key from QuestionWithAnswer)
UserAnswer=TEXT
isCorrect=BOOl
Question_ID=integer(foreign key from Question)
```

Above are my given tables with columns and i want to create 3rd table names Record by using foreign key.
This is my create stmt

```
  TABLE Records
(
  id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  DateWithTime   DATETIME, 
  UserAnswer TEXT,
  isCorrect TEXT,
  Question_ID TEXT

  FOREIGN KEY(DateWithTime) REFERENCES QuestionWithAnswer(Date),
  FOREIGN KEY(Question_ID) REFERENCES Question(question_ID),
);
```

but it is giving me error as
" QLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: CREATE TABLE Records
(
  id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  DateWithTime   DATETIME, 
  UserAnswer TEXT,
  isCorrect TEXT,
  Question_ID TEXT

FOREIGN KEY(DateWithTime) REFERENCES QuestionWithAnswer(Date),
  FOREIGN KEY(Question_ID) REFERENCES Question(question_ID),
); [ near "FOREIGN": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement] ".

Comment: Just execute the correct [CREATE TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statement. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors in the syntax:

- Add a `,` before the first `FOREIGN KEY` table constraint.
- Remove the `,` before the closing `)` paren.

Answer (score 0):

after you define your attribut, add this following code

FOREIGN KEY (colonne_name) REFERENCES parent_table_name(colonne_name)